# Showing that a functor $Cat\to Set$ is representable

Tags: category-theory, functors, representable-functor

The problem is to show that the functor from the category of small categories to the category of sets that sends a category to its set of morphisms is representable.

The major problem is to find a small category $S$ such that for any small category $A$, the set $Cat(S,A)$ is bijective to $Mor(A)$. Isn't there only one distinguished category, namely $1$? But $1$ doesn't work.

Comment: When you say $1$, do you mean the 1-point category or the catgory $a\to b$?

Comment: I mean the 1-point category.

Comment: Try the category with two objects $a,b$ and only one non-identity arrow from one object to the other, $a \rightarrow b$.

Comment: Alright, I got it.